# Send in xmlhttp numeric data converted into a character string

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send numerical data through a `GET` retrieved via `Javascript` `GPS` `position.coords.latitude` here is the code.

```js
function post() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  var v2 = -20.9008623; //position.coords.latitude;
  var v3 = 55.4958068; //position.coords.longitude;
  var v4 = v2.toString();
  var v5 = v3.toString();
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("LAT=" + v4 + "&LON=" + v5);
}
```

As you can see, `var2` and `var3` are numeric data and are indeed sent in this case since they are converted into a character string before being sent by the `GET`.
On the other hand as soon as I do the recovery by `position.coords.latitude` nothing is sent or rather nothing is recovered by the `AJAX` file.

Did I forget something? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I don't see, anywhere in your code, the `position.coords.latitude` line !

Comment: When v2 is defined as:
v2 = -20.9008623;
it works.
But when
v2 = position.coords.latitude;
it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You cant send anything else then strings with urlencoded content. Use another format.

Try with a `FormData` for instance.

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('lat', 37)
data.append('long', 32)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('content-type: multipart/form-data;')
xmlhttp.send(data)
```